# How do i join words together?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to join user input together if there are spaces in between. I tried this but it's not working.

The JavaScript code:

```
function removeSpaces() { 
    originalText = document.getElementById("cuname").text;
    removedSpacesText = originalText.split(" ").join(""); 
}
```

I placed the above code in my body section while the one below is in my head section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I have tried the ones that worked in fiddle. Still the same problem. I will be glad if you can help and show me what errors I am making.

The HTML input form is this

```
<label>Username</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="cuname" placeholder="enter username" onchange="removeSpaces()">
```

Comment: look at [string.replace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-replace/)

Answer (score 2):

Hi welcome to Stack Overflow,
I think the code below will fix your problem

```
<script>
    function removeWhiteSpaces(str){
       return str.replace(/\s/g,'');
    }
    const input = document.getElementById("cuname");
    input.addEventListener("blur",()=>{
        originalValue = input.value;
        newValue = removeWhiteSpaces(input.value);
        alert(newValue);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Could it be the code in my head section with issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line

`originalText = document.getElementById("cuname").text`

If you need to read the text value from an input you need to use the `value` attribute not the `text`.

This should work

```
function removeSpaces() { 
    originalText =  document.getElementById("cuname").value;
    removedSpacesText = originalText.split(" ").join("");
}
```

Although you have to make more changes to actually change the value in the input field

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
function replaceSpace(str){
return str.replace(/[ ]/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following HTML and JS code may fix the issue

```
<input id="test" onchange="redirect()" type=text>
<div id="divID"></div>
```

And Here is the JS Function

```
function redirect() {
    var div = document.getElementById('divID');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('test');
    final = ""
    var url = document.getElementById('test').value
    
    for (i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        if (url[i] != " ") {
            final = final + url[i];
        }
    }
    
    div.innerHTML += final
    div2.style.display = "none"    
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle I created using the same code https://jsfiddle.net/ynzm6fue/

Comment: I want to make the input text to change when the user is done typing. I.e when he gets out of the input box then his texts changes to the new value. I don't want a button

Comment: Hey I just reedited the code and the JSFiddle have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/o3k1n68v/

Comment: Glad to hear that. It will be really great if you could my answer as "Answered" If it resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

It's quick and easy with a regular expression.

```js
function RemoveSpaces() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    name = name.replace(/ +/g, "");
    console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<input id="name" onblur="RemoveSpaces()"/>
```